# php session memcache session killed when multiple requests during same session (about 40-50)

Tags: php, session, memcached

I am using memcache for php sessions as defined below.

```
session.save_handler=memcache
; Defines a comma separated of server urls to use for session storage
session.save_path="tcp://10.x.x.x:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"


cat /etc/sysconfig/memcached
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="2048"
CACHESIZE="128"
OPTIONS="-l 0.0.0.0"
```

I was doing load testing and noticed when executing the same script which connects to the database for a 1-2 second query. I then do mysql show processlist and I watch the connections go from sleep to running. After about 10-20 queries have executed all the sleeping queries drop off and the session is destroyed in memcache.

If I switch to file based sessions everything works as expected and the session does not get killed.

Memcache memory limit is 128mb of memory max connection 2048 port 11211

What could be causing this issue?

EDIT:

The session gets destroyed at exactly 30 seconds from the first request

Comment: What are you putting in the session?

Comment: what is the connection between memcache and your DB in this case?

Comment: I am not adding anything to the session when running the query. Just reading it. There is no connection between database and memcache except for the fact the session dies before the queries can run. (the scripts pile up because only one script can read/write from the session at once)